# How to detect connectivity to my server using Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

The users of my Silverlight application will access the server via a VPN connection.  Thus, the built in NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable is of no use.

I tried 2 different methods for checking connection to my server; WebClient and a WCF service.

As for the service, I tried the following method.  I can't see how I would use a regular service call since the return handler would never hit.

```
var ping = new PingServiceClient();  
ping.InnerChannel.Open( new TimeSpan(1500) );  
var result = ping.State == CommunicationState.Opened;
```

Using WebClient, I tried this:

```
var client = new WebClient();  
client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show( "Returned from server" ); };  
client.OpenReadAsync( new PingServiceClient().Endpoint.Address.Uri );
```

In both cases, the results were the same (indicates connected) whether or not I was connected to the server (I pushed the samples to the live server and connected/disconnected using the VPN client.

The next thing I would try is sockets, but just getting a working sample is beyond difficult.  Before going down that road any further, is there some other way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

The WebClient will probably return completed regardless. You'll need to check if there was an error in the request.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += (s,e) => 
{ 
    if (e.Error == null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Returned from server");
    }
}
client.OpenReadAsync( new PingServiceClient().Endpoint.Address.Uri );
```

Comment: Well, that does the exact same thing, but it made me think about the obvious - actually grab some resource and read it in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I placed a small text file on the server and read it's contents.  So this test worked reliably [edit: see comment]:

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            if ( e.Error == null )
            {
                var bytesReceived = new byte[ e.Result.Length ];
                e.Result.Read( bytesReceived, 0, 50 );
                var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length );
                if ( result.Contains( "pingback" ) )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Server up");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show( "Server down" );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Server down");
            }
        };
        var uri = string.Format( "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", App.Current.Host.Source.Scheme, "://", App.Current.Host.Source.DnsSafeHost, ":", App.Current.Host.Source.Port, "/Ping.txt" );
        client.OpenReadAsync( new Uri(uri) );
```

Comment: OK, disregard.  Initial tests were deceiving somehow.  Once I implemented a fuller example, *even this* would repeatedly return true (with no delay) after initially called while connected and subsequently calling after disconnecting.  Some kind of caching is going on somewhere (whether in or out of browser).